# Azure ACS : ACS50000 error on getting ACS token

Tags: azure, token, wcf-security, acs, azure-acs

I am using my custom STS as IDP with Azure ACS with a WCF service as RP.

I am getting the following error while getting the ACS token-

ACS10002: An error occurred while processing the SOAP body. ACS50000: There was an error issuing a token.
Trace ID: 810078c0-d799-4652-9152-cff0b730d4bd
Timestamp: 2013-10-19 14:18:29Z

The error is not giving me a clue as to what is happening actually. Is there a way to ask the MS support to use the trace id to get the error details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you have a [support plan](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/plans/) you can provide the trace ID you see along with your subscription and ACS namespace and they should be able to look up the issue.

Before you try support however, make sure you explore the exception for more than just the Message property.  Usually there is a lot more information buried within the exception in the details or inner exception.

Here is a link to the [ACS Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg185949.aspx) on MSDN.